# Fragment not showing icon

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm having trouble with an android app, mainly because when I load a fragment into the activity it never shows the icon in the app (it shows the 3 dots as if there's no space for the icon to show and it displays the text instead).
My activity is using a navigation drawer I don't know if it has to do with the problem, I've read several answers with the same problem but none of the solutions seem to affect the behaviour. 
If I add the icon programatically it shows fine, but whenever I try to use the XML it never shows the icon as action.

I'm targeting minSDK = 14 and targetSDK = 19

Here's my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
List<DrawerItem> dataList;
CustomDrawerAdapter adapter;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);


    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvNavigationDrawer);
    //mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    //mMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_array);
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Perfil", R.drawable.ic_perfil));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Code Redeemer", R.drawable.ic_coderedeemer));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Mi ID", R.drawable.ic_id));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Sucursales", R.drawable.ic_sucursales));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("GP Finder", R.drawable.ic_finder));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Calculadora Intercambio", R.drawable.ic_intercambio));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Notificaciones", R.drawable.ic_configuracion));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Configuración", R.drawable.ic_configuracion));

    adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this,R.layout.custom_drawer_item, dataList);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    //mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.drawer_list_item,mMenuTitles));


}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

/** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
private void selectItem(int position) {
    Fragment content;
    // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on position
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            content = new StubFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            content = new FinderFragment();
            break;
        default:
            content = new FinderFragment();
    }
    setTitle(dataList.get(position).getItemName());
    // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.flFragmentContainer, content)
            .commit();

    // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(dataList.get(position).getItemName());
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    return mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    //Pass any configuration change to the drawer
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

}
```

FinderFragment.java

```
public class FinderFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_finder, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    /*menu.add(Menu.NONE,  /*//** group ID.. not really needed unless you're working with groups **//**//**//**//*
            0,         /*//** this is the items ID (get this in onOptionsItemSelected to determine what was clicked) **//**//**//**//*
            Menu.NONE, /*//** ORDER.. this is what you want to change **//**//**//**//*
            R.string.search_product) /*//** title **//**//**//**//*
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);*/ //THIS WORKS CORRECTLY
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment_finder, menu);
    //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0:
            return false;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

menu_fragment_finder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/search_product"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Comment: make your class extend from ActionBarActivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the native action bar, not the `appcompat-v7` backport, as evidenced by your inheriting from `Activity` and calling `getActionBar()`. Hence, remove the `app` namespace from your menu resource and change your `app:showAsAction` to `android:showAsAction`.

Comment: Wow, I'm so dumb, since the IDE marked it as an error when I put android:showAsAction, I changed it to app:showAsAction but that was my mistake for not reading. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user2844810: Yeah, that Lint warning is irritating.